# Customer groups determine css

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.5

Is it possible to have a customer group/user group using 1 specific CSS file. Maybe have a database with all store names in and different groups and the CSS file they use from a server?

Comment: I am glad a new contributor in magento stackexchange, is below answer helpful please accept the answer or comment your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you could create a new module that adds a custom layout handle for each customer group by observing event 'controller_action_layout_load_before'.
In the layout file you could add a css-file for that specific group.

Here's a nice howto: https://www.atwix.com/magento/magento-customer-group-layout-handle/

It applies to Magento 1.x, but the logic is similar.

Hth, Tom

Comment: Thank you for the howto it was very helpful